# CommandName issues to insert to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code, when we define the parameters CommandName="Insert" is it actually the same as executing the method Insert? As I can't find Insert anywhere...

```
<div class="actionbuttons">
                        <Club:RolloverButton ID="apply1" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add Event" runat="server" />
                        <Club:RolloverLink ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" NavigateURL='<%# "Events_view.aspx?EventID=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("ID")) %>' />
                    </div>
```

I have the following SqlDataSource as well:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ClubSiteDB %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.Events.id, dbo.Events.starttime, dbo.events.endtime, dbo.Events.title, dbo.Events.description, dbo.Events.staticURL, dbo.Events.photo,  dbo.Events.location, dbo.Locations.title AS locationname FROM  dbo.Events LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Locations ON dbo.Events.location = dbo.Locations.id where Events.id=@id"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Events(starttime, endtime, title, description, staticURL, location, photo) VALUES (@starttime, @endtime,  @title, @description, @staticURL, @location, @photo)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Events SET starttime = @starttime, endtime=@endtime, title = @title, description = @description, staticURL = @staticURL, location = @location, photo = @photo WHERE (id = @id)"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE Events WHERE id=@id" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="starttime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="endtime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="title" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="description" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="staticURL" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="location" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="photo" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="starttime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="endtime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="title" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="description" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="staticURL" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="location" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="photo" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="ID" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want it to insert using the InsertCommand, however when I do SqlDataSource1.Insert() it's complaining that starttime is NULL

Comment: Could you paste the code where you set Insert parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error is for the starttime value not being set, the error might be related to the field you are using to get the starttime value.  Are you using a Bind("starttime") instead of Eval("starttime")?

```
Bind("starttime")
```

Updated:
Are you setting the paramter? if not you should tell the SqlDataSource where to get it.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="starttime" ControlID="dtpicker"
                   PropertyName="startDateTime" Type="DateTime" />
```

Comment: yes I am using Bind starttime, which is weird.. by default even if the user did not choose anything it should have some value.. 

<Club:Durationpicker ID="dtpicker" runat="server" startDateTime='<%#Bind("Starttime") %>'
                                    enddatetime='<%#Bind("endtime") %>' />

Comment: Also how do I check if there's a data inserted to the database?